# How to reuse backbone.js views as hosted widgets?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, widget

My company runs an e-commerce website, built on top of backbone.js framework. Although I'm not a web programmer, I understood that each module in the website (category pages, product pages) are rendered using the relevant view/template pair. We would like to offer to publisher sites to host our product pages as widgets. I understand that this requires some js code on our side that the hosting site should download in order to display the widget. Is it possible to extract the relevant view/template pieces from the website code base and make it standalone in  that js code? I guess it requires injecting the relevant css and js libs to the calling page, are there some frameworks to ease that process?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

How to inject css and image files, using backbone and requirejs.

*Step 1 :*

Initialize the overall structure of the product module, with a Backbone Model, a Backbone View, an underscore template, and finally the main.js that will call the module.

_Note__ : I organize my structure by module, that is `product/model.js`, `product/view.js` although you're free to organize as you want.
What is usually seen is `models/productModel.js`, `views/product.js`.

```
   // @file: product/model.js
   // @info: Given a product model:
   var ProductModel = Backbone.Model.extend({ [...] });

   // @file: product/view.js
   // @info: Given a product view:
   var ProductView = Backbone.View.extend({ });

   // @file: layouts/template/productView.html
   // @info: Template view
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="asset/css/product/item.css">
   <script type="text/template" id="product-view">
       <div class="product details">
          <h2><%= name %></h2>
          <img class="thumb" src="<%= src %>">
          <div class="price"><%= price %></div>
       </div>
   </script>

   // @file: main.js
   // instanciate the model
   var productModel, productView;
   productModel = new ProductModel({ 
       id: 1, 
       name: "myProduct", 
       src: "assets/image/my_product.png",
       price: 321,
   });

   productView = new ProductView({
       model: productModel
   });
```

*Step 2 :*

Add require.js to load asynchronously the js files:

```
   // @file: index.html
   // @info: display root file
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en">
   <head>
       [...]
   </head>
   <body>
   [...]
   <!-- load the requirejs lib -->
   <script src="assets/vendor/require.js" data-main="assets/js/main.js" />
   </body>
```

In main.js, we will need to config the requirejs lib. 
First, shim the needed librariries (backbone, underscore, jquery).

```
   // @file: main.js
   // add requirejs config, which bind the needed libraries
   require.config({
       paths: {
           jquery: "../vendor/jquery",
           underscore: "../vendor/underscore",
           backbone: "../vendor/backbone",
           // requirejs text module
           // https://github.com/requirejs/text
           text: "../vendor/text"
       },
       shim: {
           jquery: {
               exports: "$"
           },
           underscore: {
               exports: "_"
           },
           backbone: {
               // Backbone needs these dependencies
               // so when we require(["backbone"])
               // it will also load jquery and underscore
               deps: ["jquery", "underscore"],
               exports: "Backbone"
           }
       },
   });
   // instanciate the model
   require(
      ["Backbone", "product/view", "product/model"],
      function (Backbone, ProductView, ProductModel) {
          var productModel, productView;
          productModel = new ProductModel({ 
             id: 1, 
             name: "myProduct", 
             src: "assets/image/my_product.png",
             price: 321,
         });

        productView = new ProductView({
           model: productModel
        });
      }
    );
```

Need to do the same for product Backbone files :

```
// @file: product/model.js
define(["backbone"], function (Backbone) {
    var ProductModel = Backbone.Model.extend({ [...] });
    return ProductModel; 
});

// @file: product/view.js
define(
     ["backbone", "product/model", "text!layouts/template/productView.html"],
     function (Backbone, ProductModel, ProductTemplate) {
         var ProductView = Backbone.View.extend({ 
             [...]
             template: _.template(ProductTemplate),
             initialize: function (data) {
                 this.model = data.model;
                 return this;
             },
             render: function () {
                this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
             }
         });
         return ProductView;
     }
);
```

**Step 3 (optimization & suggestions) :**

Consider this as optional.

Backbone is great because it's lightweight. You can make it more lightweight, by using [Backbone.Native](https://github.com/inkling/backbone.native) as a replacment of jquery.

You can even replace Backbone by [ExoJs](http://exosjs.com/) which remove the jquery and underscore dependencies.

You can load asynchronously image :

with [LazyLoad](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/lazy-loading-images/).

update `layouts/template/productView.html` :

```
       // @file: layouts/template/productView.html
       // @info: Template view
       [...]
       <script type="text/template" id="product-view">
           <div class="product details">
              <h2><%= name %></h2>
              <img class="thumb lazy" src="assets/image/blank.gif" data-src="<%= src %>" height="<%= image.height %>" width= "<%= image.width %>">
              <div class="price"><%= price %></div>
           </div>
       </script>
```

update `main.js` :

```
  require.config({
       paths : { 
           [...],
           "lazyload": "../js/vendor/lazyload"

  });
  require(
      ["Backbone", "lazyload", "product/view", "product/model"],
      function (Backbone, LazyLoad, ProductView, ProductModel) {
          var productModel, productView;
          productModel = new ProductModel({ 
             id: 1, 
             name: "myProduct", 
             src: "assets/image/my_product.png",
             price: 321,
             image: {
                 width: "100px",
                 height: "100px"
             }
          });

          productView = new ProductView({
             model: productModel
          });
      }
    );
```

For css, as you might noticed, I load a css module in the template view. 
This is not optimal, since it's better to concat into a big css file, to reduce the number of http request.

The purpose of loading a module css is : when you finished loading the "core" css file, you can async load a part of css. So you get the basic content fast, then you get the details of each content after.

Remove the link to css file in `layouts/template/productView.html`.
Add [Toast](https://github.com/pyrsmk/toast) in your requirejs paths.
Add an extra `css` property when instanciate the model.

```
productModel = new ProductModel({
    css: "asset/css/product/item.css"
    [...]
});
```

Replace `product/view.js`

```
// @file: product/view.js
define(
     ["backbone", "toast", "product/model", "text!layouts/template/productView.html"],
     function (Backbone, Toast, ProductModel, ProductTemplate) {
         var ProductView = Backbone.View.extend({ 
             [...]
             template: _.template(ProductTemplate),
             initialize: function (data) {
                 this.model = data.model;
                 Toast(this.model.css);
                 return this;
             },
             render: function () {
                this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
             }
         });
         return ProductView;
     }
);
```

---

[requirejs](http://requirejs.org) or [browserify](http://browserify.org/) to ease the process of injecting javascript.

[Backbone & Requirejs tuto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14517586/2535516)

For better modularity, use a template engine. [underscore](http://underscorejs.org), as well as [lodash](http://lodash.com) have one. But you can [use a lot more](http://garann.github.io/template-chooser/)

Requirejs doesnt load asynchronously css, [yepnope.js](http://yepnopejs.com/) does. As a side note, yepnope is included in modernizrjs, if you use it. There is also [lazyload](https://github.com/rgrove/lazyload), [l.js](http://malko.github.io/l.js/), [toast](https://github.com/pyrsmk/toast)

Comment: Is it possible to inject css and images files as well? Can you point me to a step-by-step guide how to achieve that?